# PHP/MySQL - query fails if a variable is used instead of a hard coded value

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

I've searched and searched and tried the things I've read but for some reason my query fails when using a variable rather than a hardcoded value.

This is my query:

```
$bugzilla_query="SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE userid='".$bugzilla_id."'";
```

I am getting the value of the cookie by doing the following:

```
$bugzilla_id = $_COOKIE["Bugzilla_login"];
```

I am starting to doubt that the query is wrong but the variable holding the cookie value is not retrieving it correctly even though it looks correct but then again if I set `$bugzilla_id = 642;` it still doesn't work but if I do `$bugzilla_query="SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE userid=642";` it works perfectly.

Hmm, confused!

Comment: user a `var_dump` to see what is in `$bugzilla_query`

Comment: I copied the same syntax from another script that works fine with variables in it. I added some whitespace in but still no luck :(

Comment: Make sure to properly escape your data to avoid SQL injection

Comment: @Doug T: I don't believe that there are ." and .$ tokens in PHP.

Comment: @Neal - seems to be set to NULL. What I have done is written a function to connect to the Bugzilla database and I echo `getBugzillaShortname();` to get the value as I am returning a variable at the end of the function.

Comment: Check the value in the cookie with `var_dump($bugzilla_id)`. It may look like an integer, but coul dhave hidden spaces or something. If you're querying with quotes around it, then mysql may be trying to do a straight integer->string comparison and fail.

Comment: Hi Marc, the variable just seems to come out as `NULL`. If I echo the query I get this: `SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE userid = 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks very much for all your help. Turns out it was a stupid typo I made in my code:

I had:

```
if ($bugzilla_id <= 0 || $bugzilla_id = '' || !isset($bugzilla_id))
{
     return "No Bugzilla cookie is set!";
}
```

When I obviously needed:

```
if ($bugzilla_id <= 0 || $bugzilla_id == '' || !isset($bugzilla_id))
{
    return "No Bugzilla cookie is set!";
}
```

I was setting `$bugzilla_id` to `''` because I missed an `=` in the comparison checking.

My advice for that - and I may start doing this myself - would be to put the variable on the right hand side, so write your comparisons the opposite way round, then it will fail straight away. Coincidentally, I read on Joel's own website that he sees this as a sign of a good programmer :/

Answer (score 3):

You never want to put any value that could be modified by a user directly into a query, in general. Additionally if that's supposed to be a number, why are you putting it in single quotes in your variable enabled query, but not in your hard coded one? Notice the difference?  Try this:

```
$bugzilla_query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE userid = %d", $bugzilla_id);
```

That'll make sure it's cast as an integer before going into your query.

Comment: echo $bugzilla_query and copy/paste it into mysql and run it directly. What happens? What's the query?

Comment: Hi David, not been on SO over the weekend but just tried your suggestion. Something is playing up with the variable because the query echos out as `SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE userid = 0`

Answer (score 1):

If $bugzilla_id is supposed to be an integer, try wrapping it in an intval() to make sure it's being passed as an integer.